# Select Ran sharing file errorOverflow Vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu, overflow

I developed a macro that update information about counters per hour in a graph with a action function. It sense the user action with `Worksheet_Change` that go to a DATA sheet and filter all the cells with the same information.

[image]
The cell B1 (Validation data) is updated with `Worksheet_SelectionChange` eliminating duplicates from the data and then User can select the option they want. There are not any issues running the macro but when the update function filter more than 550 values. A MsgBox is thrown with the following message:

[image]

All the values before that index is working, it doesnt matter with string user select. This an example of a DATA table.

[image]

The next block code update the drop-down list:

```
Function Get_CluName()
    Dim Dic_Clu As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Col As Integer

    Set Dic_Clu = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Call InitSht

    If ShtData.Range("B1").Value = "LTE Cell Group" Then
        Worksheets("GRAPH").Range("A1").Value = "Select Cluster:"
        Col = 2
    ElseIf ShtData.Range("D1").Value = "Cell Name" Then
        Worksheets("GRAPH").Range("A1").Value = "Select Cell:"
        Col = 4
    End If

    For i = 2 To ShtData.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        If Len(ShtData.Cells(i, Col).Value) > 0 Then
            Dic_Clu(Trim(ShtData.Cells(i, Col).Value)) = Trim(ShtData.Cells(i, Col).Value)
        End If
    Next

    If Dic_Clu.Count > 0 Then
        Worksheets("GRAPH").Range("Z1").Resize(Dic_Clu.Count) = Application.Transpose(Dic_Clu.keys)
        Worksheets("SUMMARY LTE KPI").Range("Z1").Resize(Dic_Clu.Count) = Application.Transpose(Dic_Clu.keys)

        With Worksheets("GRAPH").Range("B1").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & Worksheets("GRAPH").Range("Z1").Resize(Dic_Clu.Count).Address
        End With

        With Worksheets("SUMMARY LTE KPI").Range("B1").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & Worksheets("SUMMARY LTE KPI").Range("Z1").Resize(Dic_Clu.Count).Address
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

**Is there any option to resize the memory of drop-down list? ** as it seems that is overflowing the list.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved!

It was due to some variables were declared as Integer into some functions, redeclared to long was the solution.